# Hyperledger Fabric- Contracts are required to have at least 1 (non-ignored) public method

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm using fabric tools provided for composer to deploy fabric network as it deploys 1 peer, 1 orderer, 1 couchdb, & 1 fabric-ca. I am able to install chain code on peer but instantiation fails with following error. I am using command on fabric-peer.

> error in simulation: failed to execute transaction
> 2037ca1d4ec2682ad17499156de49aeb28053ad5b6943f1fe3520c407bac570e:
> could not launch chaincode
> product_1.1.1:e2901eb986174a4ac9bb963b06db851ea347ed6b48930de813c3dbc38df94a82:
> chaincode registration failed: container exited with 2

when i checked the logs of docker container it is returning me this error

> 2021/07/29 08:41:29 Error create network chaincode chaincode: Contracts are required to have at least 1 (non-ignored) public method.
> Contract PRODUCTChainCode has none. Method names that have been
> ignored: GetAfterTransaction, GetBeforeTransaction, GetInfo, GetName,
> GetTransactionContextHandler, GetUnknownTransaction,
> GetIgnoredFunctions and GetEvaluateTransactions panic: Error create
> network chaincode chaincode: Contracts are required to have at least
> 1 (non-ignored) public method. Contract PRODUCTChainCode has none.
> Method names that have been ignored: GetAfterTransaction,
> GetBeforeTransaction, GetInfo, GetName, GetTransactionContextHandler,
> GetUnknownTransaction, GetIgnoredFunctions and GetEvaluateTransactions
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: log.Panicf(0xa40a03, 0x2e, 0xc00059ff68, 0x1,
> 0x1)  /usr/local/go/src/log/log.go:358 +0xc5 main.main()
> /chaincode/input/src/main.go:18 +0x1b0

here is my main.go file

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "product-chaincode/core/messages"

    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go/contractapi"
)

// PRODUCTChainCode implementation
type PRODUCTChainCode struct {
    contractapi.Contract
}

func main() {
    PRODUCTChainCode, err := contractapi.NewChaincode(&PRODUCTChainCode{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf(messages.ChaincodeCreateError, err.Error())
    }

    if err := PRODUCTChainCode.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Panicf(messages.ChaincodeStartError, err.Error())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following error message **Contracts are required to have at last 1 (non-ignored) public method."** tells us that the chain code you wrote does not have a public method.

In the Go language, functions (and variables) whose names begin with uppercase letters are treated as public and functions (and variables) whose names begin with lowercase letters are private.

Currently, there is only one main function in the chain code you created, so it seems that it cannot be executed because there is no public function.

**Try adding one public function whose function name begins with uppercase letters.**